# Background-attachment fixed doesn't work in chrome when inside a scrolling div

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, background-position

Basically, when a background image is inside a scrolling div it'll not longer act fixed and just revert back to scroll:

CSS:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

HTML:

```
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 90%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}

span{
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Q3NruNr.jpg);
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It works fine in firefox but chrome seems to not handle it. Any work around?

http://codepen.io/mattcoady/pen/BooyaZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome that happens a lot but i feel like every fix is different:(

here is a **Codepen** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvvYJz

All ive added is

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
```

to your span tag, let me know if this is the desired effect.

**Chromium issue** https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

Comment: Strange, this seemed to work yesterday and now I check again today and it doesn't work anymore. I wonder if chrome updated again :/

Comment: Worked for me (Version 45.0.2454.85 m)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NooBskie, it worked for me, using Modals from Bootstrap v3.3.2 to show fixed background:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
-moz-transform: translateY(0%);
-ms-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
```